# Integration tests for spring boot application invoked with aws msk event

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test, aws-msk, spring-boot-testcontainers

We have a spring boot application integrated with AWS managed Kafka.

We want to test 2 flows -

1. Event listener on the application. That process event and writes data from it to db.
2. Get API on the application that refers to DB and provides data.

We are able to use EmbeddedKafka and TestContainers to test this locally.
However we would like to validate it for real in QA environment. Can someone provide insights how to generate Kafka event and invoke listener for real?

For validating GET api, we are planning to use RestAssured.